# Insert data into 2 tables from 1 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `scaffold` with 2 fields `name:string, active:boolean..`

This way scaffold create data...

```
def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    render :json => @question.to_ext_json(:success => @question.save)
  end
```

Everything's good, but i want when creates question some data inserting into my another table called tokens:

In my token table there are only 2 fields: token & is_active (boolean)

```
def create
    @w = "token"
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    @token = Token.new({:token => @w, :is_active=>"1"})
    render :json => @question.to_ext_json(:success => @question.save)
  end
```

this way doesn't work. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like...

```
def create
  @w = "token"
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])

  if success = @question.save
    @token = Token.new({:token => @w, :is_active=>"1"})
    @token.save
  end

  render :json => @question.to_ext_json(:success => success)
end
```

This assumes any validation is done on the Question model. You could take this even further and use a Transaction, but that seems needlessly complicated in this case.